# How to fix the space in Safe Area of Iphone X in Ionic 4 inAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am creating a project in Ionic 4 , What I'm basically doing is displaying a website using the `inAppBrowser` of Ionic

Everything seems fine except in Iphone X . Because of the "Notch" the navbar and footer is not filling the **Safe Area**.

How do I fill the **Safe Area** ? CSS styles aren't helping at all

Here is the screenshot.

The **red box** is what i want to fill , It pushed the navbar and footer away from it

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you can try the `themeable browser` and modify the web view here is the link https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser